# Отступы у блока с flex-wrar:wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10rem;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 1rem 4rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<br/>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Логотип</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Прайс-лист</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Документация</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">События</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image]

Как избавиться в меню от отступа справа и центировать его в шапке относительно логотипа и поиска?

Comment: justify-content: center ?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/D2P19jvSW96MlA

Comment: удобнее сделать на гриде используя minmax

Comment: grid minmax не рабтает с repeat, а фиксировать количество колонок не получиться